# Is there an away to change text order with Tesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract python to extract text from tables in scanned pdf. 
Data are correctly extracted using:

`--psm 6` : that assume a single uniform block of text. I have tried this way

```
extracted_text +=  image_to_string(Image.open(image), config='--psm 6')
```

I want to change the order of the text. Is there a way to extract every column in a single line ?
A very small scale example would be:

```
Header 1    Header 2
cell 11     cell 21
cell 12     cell 22
```

And this is what I am looking for:

```
Header 1   cell 11   cell 12
Header 2   cell 21   cell 22
```

Comment: So you want to transpose recognized data? Tesseract can not do it - tesseract is just OCR engine.

Comment: Is there another way to do that if i get data in dataframe format ? because i can use tabula-py instead of tesseract.

Comment: yes, pandas has function transpose.